# Merge two arrays of object from two different columns to create a new array of unique and not null objects in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, merge

I have a result set which returns 3 columns out of which one is varchar and two are array, now i need to merge the array column to create a new array with not null unique elements. I have tried different options non of them are working, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the arrays and `unnest` into rows.  Then you can use `distinct` to get the unique rows, and `array_agg` to combine them back into an array:

```
select  id
,       array_agg(nr)
from    (
        select  distinct id
        ,       unnest(array[col1] || col2 || col3) nr
        from    t1
        ) sub
group by
        id
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7ee6c/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. I found the solution array_cat function worked for me.